Can't access Nuxt Studio data inside of Nuxt application
I have this nuxt.schema.ts it loads perfectly on https://nuxt.studio without any issues and I can alter the options, how do I access this object in my app? If I use const config = useAppConfig() it just gets the locally defined app config and doesn't access the details from the studio.
import { field, group } from "@nuxthq/studio/theme";

export default defineNuxtSchema({
  appConfig: {
    ui: group({
      title: "UI Configuration",
      description: "Configure the UI elements of your site.",
      icon: "i-mdi-palette",
      fields: {
        logo: field({
          type: "media",
          title: "Logo",
          description: "The main logo for your website.",
          icon: "i-mdi-image",
        }),
        primaryColor: field({
          type: "string",
          title: "Primary Color",
          description: "The primary color for your website's theme.",
          icon: "i-mdi-palette",
          default: "#3B82F6",
        }),
        backgroundColor: field({
          type: "string",
          title: "Background Color",
          description: "The base/background color for your website.",
          icon: "i-mdi-format-color-fill",
          default: "#FFFFFF",
        }),
      },
    }),
  },
});


It seems it was a case of me not pulling the changes that were made in the editor and my app.config.ts  wasn't setup to mirror the nuxt.schema.ts.
